# ngIf multiple conditions not working with router.url

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to hide a div based on routes. If the router url is login or forgot password than hide the div.Here is the code and its not working.

```
<div class="isNotLogin" *ngIf="router.url != '/login' || router.url != '/forgot-password'">
hide this content
</div>
```

But its working for single condition:

```
<div class="isNotLogin" *ngIf="router.url != '/login'">
hide this content
</div>
```

Any Idea?

Comment: This logic does not makes sense - you cannot be the same time on login and forgot-password thus it is true always. Either change to && or change conditions to ===

Comment: @Antoniossss - I was about to post an answer for `&&`. Will you post one?

Comment: I have another div which displays on login or forgot password router url. This div is a canvas behind which is hard coded, I can't remove it or move it at the moment.

Comment: @ConnorsFan go ahead - playing SC2 now ;P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to hide Div only if login or password. you need to use ===.

```
<div class="isNotLogin" *ngIf="!(router.url === '/login' || router.url === '/forgot-password')">
hide this content
</div>
```

Comment: Added Not operator. please check now.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya you should update your answer, the issue is not the operator, but the wrong condition.

Comment: Thanks I was searching for this exact answer

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @Suresh's answer, according to [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#put-presentation-logic-in-the-component-class), you should put presentation logic in the Component Class instead of the template itself. This improves testability, maintainability, and reusability.

Move the logic to show/hide the div in a function in the Component Class and then call it from `*ngIf` in your template.

```
@Component({ ... })
export class YourComponent {

  ...

  shouldShow() {
    return !(router.url === '/login' || router.url === '/forgot-password');
  }

  ...

}
```

And in your template.

```
<div 
  class="isNotLogin" 
  *ngIf="shouldShow()">
  hide this content
</div>
```